# "breakpoint command add" does not work in LLDB command line in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-studio, lldb

As far as I know, `lldb` supports automatic command execution when breakpoint is hit (similar to `gdb`'s `commands`).

[Manual](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) says it should work like this:

```
(lldb) breakpoint command add 1.1 
Enter your debugger command(s). Type 'DONE' to end. 
> bt 
> DONE
```

This one should output backtrace each time when breakpoint 1.1 is hit. I am trying to do the same thing in LLDB console in Android Studio 2.1.2 with NDK version 12b:

```
(lldb) breakpoint list
...
8: file = '/home/user/src_file.cpp', line = 2683, exact_match = 0, locations = 1, resolved = 1, hit count = 1
  8.1: where = libdroid_shared.so`(anonymous namespace)::onDbgThreadResume() + 20 at src_file.cpp:2683, address = 0x0000007f9cad6740, resolved, hit count = 1 

(lldb) breakpoint command add 8.1
(lldb) breakpoint command add 8.1
(lldb)
```

As you can see, the debugger does not offer me to enter commands. When I press Enter after `breakpoint commmand add` line it just outputs empty line, and there's no command line prompt.

I tried both 32 and 64 bit debuggers, with different files, breakpoints and apps, but it does not work.
The same thing with `gdb`'s `commands` works perfectly.

My questions:

- Is this a known bug in Android Studio or lldb, is there a workaround?
- Maybe this is just a bug in Android Studio UI? Can I use lldb without Android Studio, just the command line interface? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Android Studio, but this looks like it is a bug in Android studio or the lldb "MI" emulation layer in the handling of lldb's input callbacks (in this case the one prompting for the actual commands.)

If that's what it is, you can work around it by putting your commands in a file, then using the "one-line" input option like:

```
(lldb) br com add -o "com source /tmp/lldb.cmds"
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. This actually changes something, after this in the `breakpoint list` I see that breakpoint 8.1 has commands from `/tmp/lldb.cmds`. However they don't seem to get executed, I see nothing in the output when breakpoint is hit.
Content of my file is simply `bt`, is it okay? I expect to see backtrace printed each time breakpoint is hit. LLDB implementation in Android Studio is so messy, but maybe still I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you try doing something that has side-effects in your breakpoint command file (e.g. set another breakpoint.)  Then you can tell when you hit the breakpoint whether the commands have been executed.  If they have (which I bet will be the case) then this looks like a bug in gathering lldb output in Android Studio.

Comment: I tried to add "continue" in there and it clearly was ignored. At least my program was still stopped on breakpoint instead of being continued.

Comment: so far it looks like a bug, I filed a bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215718
This is really unfortunate. I also can't figure out how to launch lldb remote debugging standalone, without Android Studio. If you have such experience and can help me, that would be just amazing. I've spent hours without success, so I'd be happy to give 100 or 200 bounty points for that :)

Comment: I have never worked with Android Studio, so I don't know how it works.  It must start up some debug agent (probably an lldb_server instance) on the device and then tells itself what port it is listening on.  If you could figure out how it does that, then in lldb you would use the "gdb-remote" command to connect to that port & drive the debug session.  The lldb part would be pretty simple, and if you can get the debug agent started, I could help with the lldb side.  But I don't know how you start the debug agent, sorry...

Comment: Note, some of the folks who work on lldb for Android are on the lldb-dev list: http://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/lldb-dev so you could ask there.

Comment: thank you for your help. In the end, I managed to build lldb-3.9 client from source, and as remote agent I am using lldb-server that comes with Android SDK. It is working, I was able to attach to process. However lldb fails to read debugging symbols from my .so library, even when I add it with "target modules add". See also here: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26289#c6

Comment: The current Android Studio bug report is at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37109717, where more discussion can be found.